# How to join two RDD's in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm having trouble finding the right way to join to RDD's in PySpark to achieve a desired result.

```
Here is the first RDD:
+------+---+
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
|Python| 36|
|     C|  6|
|    C#|  8|
+------+---+

Here is the second RDD:
+------+---+
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
|Python| 10|
|     C|  1|
|    C#|  1|
+------+---+

Here is the result I want:
+------+---+---+
|    _1| _2| _3|
+------+---+---+
|Python| 36| 10|
|     C|  6|  1|
|    C#|  8|  1|
+------+---+---+
```

I've tried all sorts of `.join()` and `.union()` variations between the two RDD's but can't get it right, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### With RDD

```py
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('python', 36), ('c', 6), ('c#', 8)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([('python', 10), ('c', 1), ('c#', 1)])
rdd1.join(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[0], *x[1])).toDF().show()
+------+---+---+
|    _1| _2| _3|
+------+---+---+
|python| 36| 10|
|     c|  6|  1|
|    c#|  8|  1|
+------+---+---+
```

###### With DF

```py
df1 = rdd1.toDF(['c1', 'c2'])
df2 = rdd2.toDF(['c1', 'c3'])
rdd3 = df1.join(df2, on=['c1'], how='inner').rdd
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The way I'm implementing my project requires me to perform this join as an RDD and convert it to a data frame later on, is there no way to do the join method you mentioned but for an RDD instead?

Comment: I don't see why you **must** do it with RDD. As long as you have your RDD (and interact with it), you always can convert to DF back and forth

Comment: I tried converting my RDD to a data frame but since my project uses spark streaming, it said I can't use .toDF() on a DStream.

Comment: I see, check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much!! you saved my project & and my grades, also no idea how I could've come to that answer on my own haha

Comment: Not sure if your gonna see this but I asked a similar question to this again on my stack overflow, it's about joining another RDD to the 3 column rdd3, I couldn't manage to get a solution using your method, could you help out?